# Losing stdout when process restarts itself in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, stdout

I have for example a NodeJS process running with Nodemon, and all the output redirected to a file.

```
nodemon example.app > 123.log
```

When I change any file in the node app, the NodeJS process is restarting itself and after that all log messages go to nirvana.

Is there a way in windows to catch the output of a process and all the subprocesses it might create?